# View function for browsing a dataset

Tags: r, database, view, rstudio

Suppose you have a large dataset, say with 100 columns. The only way I know to browse the dataset is to use the function View(). However, there is something particularly annoying with that function. Indeed, if I want to browse the fifty-first column, and I've already scrolled the dataset, say I'm in the middle of the dataset, then when I click to see columns 51-100, I come back to the first observation and If I scroll the dataset I cannot understand what I'm looking at because I cannot block the first column describing the data.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Save as a csv and view in excel?

Comment: You might want to take a look at IDEs like RStudio https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RStudio where you can setup things like previews etc.

Comment: I experienced this a bit with RStudio. It helps if you have an ID column, that way, when you go to the columns 51-100, you can still filter by the ID column and get the row you are looking for